# for project euler number 4 i am just wondering what is wrong with my code. have been knacking my brain and i do not know how, this is on python

Tags: python

```
x=100
y=100
z=str(x*y)
k=[]
while x<=999 and y<=999:
    if z==int(z[::-1]):
        k.insert(z)
    x+=1
    y+=1
print(k)
```

this just produced an empty bracket, i want to know why and how i can fix this. thanks

Comment: `list.insert` needs index as the first argument and second argument is the value to be inserted. You need to use `.append`. Checkout [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) documentation to read more about list methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if z==int(z[::-1]):
```

This condition is always false because `z` never changes in the loop, and because z is a string so it will never equal an `int`

After fixing that your code will still fail because `x` and `y` are always equal.

Comment: thanks i just started coding since the past two weeks and this really helped thanks